# Server crashes when scraping using cURL & simple_html_dom

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm having a strange issue. I have a script that works fine on localhost but when running it on a server it crashes after a few loops. The script uses `cURL` and `simple_html_dom` to scrape web pages.

Here is a sum of the code:

```
    class updateController extends Controller{
        function __construct(){
            ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
            set_time_limit(0);
            require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
        }
static public function ThemeforestLoopExisting(){
   $themes = Fulls::where('X','Y')->get();

   foreach($themes as $theme){
       $cURL = GeneralFunctions::cURLDom($theme['url']);
     //Here I search for specific parts on the web page using the "find" method on simple_html_dom
   }
}



  }
```

In `GeneralFunctions.php:`

```
    static public function cURL_scraping($url){
        $curl = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
         curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A');
         curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Expect:'));
         curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');
        $response['str'] = curl_exec($curl);


        $response['header'] = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close($curl);
        return $response;
    }

    static public function cURLDom($url){

  $cURL_results   = generalFunctions::cURL_scraping($url);
  $res['header']  = $cURL_results['header'];
  $res['str']  = str_get_html($cURL_results['str'],$lowercase=false, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=false, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT);
  return $res['str'];
}
```

The entire thing works for the first 10/20/30 runs or so and then the server crashes. It works perfectly on localhost.
I spoke to my webhost but they were no help.

Is there anything that I'm missing or not realizing here?
Any help would be much appreciated...
Thank you!

Comment: The *server* crashes? Or the script?

Comment: Crashes with what error? `max_execution_time` perhaps?

Comment: The server crashes - I get a 500 error with this message: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@xxxxxxx.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Ok, that's not the server crashing. That's the script failing and the web service returning an error code. The web server log file should contain details of the issue.

Comment: I couldn't find anything useful in the log, even the webhost had no idea. BTW - when a script is written incorrectly or whatever I would normally get a Laravel error, in this case I don't get that same kind of error

Comment: `memory_limit` errors will sometimes cause 500s with no associated error log.

Comment: I thought so too. I changed the memory to unlimited and that didn't work (now that i think of it - do i need to restart the server for that?), but that's not a good solution. Is there a way to use unlimited memory on a file basis?

Comment: If you changed the value in `php.ini` then you need to restart. You can change the value for one script via `ini_set()`.

Comment: I set it to unlimited and it still crashes. Any other ideas?

Comment: There are known performance issues. Maybe try [an alternative](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom)

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a database issue. I changed the collation to `utf8mb4_general_ci` and that fixed it.